# NSData dataWithContentsOfURL erroneous?

Tags: objective-c, nsdata

Trying to parse simple URL with NSData but fails:

```
NSURL* url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://192.168.2.105:80"];
NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error];
```

Result is
error = Cocoa error 256

What reason?

Comment: You need to send a NSURLRequest, you don't read a file downloaded from the web in this way.

Comment: What do you mean? dataWithContentsOfURL takes an NSURL argument - not NSURLRequest

Comment: If replace with http://www.google.com:80 it works. Wtf?

Comment: It should be on your file system, not on the web.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this:

```
NSURL* URL=[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.google.com"];
NSURLRequest* req=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL: URL];
NSData* data=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: req returningResponse: nil error: nil];
```

That's a short example, I recommend to check out the response and the eventual error.

**EDIT**

You were right about using dataWithContentOfURL, the code that I posted does the same thing.
But it's the URL to be wrong.You should pass something like *http://www.site.org* .